# Specific deadlock scenario when using asynchronous code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, deadlock

I've read for hours about the Task based Asynchronous Pattern.
And now I try to prove myself I understood it properly, so I forced myself into the following excercice:

Inside a WebApi controller, wait for an `async` operation in a non `async` one and try to access `ControllerContext` afterward.
But things don't flow the way I though they would.

EDIT: Code misleading, don't consider it...

```
//using System.Diagnostics;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using System.Web.Http;
//namespace DeadlockTest.Controllers
//{
//    public class ValuesController : ApiController
//    {
//        public string Get()
//        {
//            var task = DoSomething();
//            //task.Wait();
//            task.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
//            return ControllerContext?.ToString();  // not reached
//        }
//        private async Task DoSomething()
//        {
//            await Task.Delay(new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100));
//            Debugger.Break(); // not reached
//        }
//    }
//}
```

I'm astonished `Debugger.Break();` is not reached!

Even if I just call `task.Wait();`.

`task.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is a bit awkward and it's just a random shot at being able to wait for a task which shouldn't "block" the current SynchronizationContext.

How can this be solved, knowing the methods signature must not change* (for this exercice to bear any meaning to me)?

- thus no `public async string Get()` to save the day

EDIT:

```
    public void LogGet()
    {
        Action get = Get;
        var logger = new RussianOpCodeLibrary.ActionLogger(get);

        logger.Dosvidaniya();
    }

    private void Get()
    {
        DoSomething().Wait();
    }

    private async Task DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Delay(new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100));

        Debugger.Break(); // not reached
    }
```

Comment: `Get()` is *your* method, not an overload. Change your signature to  `async Task<string> Get()` or `async Task<string> GetAsync()`. The suffix doesn't matter as far as asynchronous operation is concerned. The deadlock is caused by your code, because you call `.Wait` or `.Result` (.GetResult() blocks too)

Comment: If you insist in not changing the signature to `async Task<string> Get()` you haven't understood what `async/await` is.  *Your* code is *not* asynchronous if you block and don't use `await`. Asynchronous means that you start an already asynchronous operation an `await` for it to finish without blocking the current thread.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I guess I can solve this using Delegate Tasks.

```
    public string Get()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var task = DoSomething();
            task.Wait();
        }).Wait();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var task = DoSomething();
            await task;
        }).Unwrap().Wait();
        //task.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        return ControllerContext?.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "delegate task". You *don't* need any more tasks, just change the signature of `Get` to `async Task<string> Get` to use `await. *This* code isn't asynchronous, it's actually *slower* than the original because it uses at least two extra threads - why use `await taks` inside `StartNew` ? Just return the task you alrady have

Comment: PS if this is homework, you *will* fail it with anything other than `await DoSomething();`.  If you don't, ask for a refund and find another tutor

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's an exercise I force myself into. Sometimes in life you don't have full control over the whole codebase and there are signatures you have to accept and deal with. Apparently someone can't stand the idea and downvoted my answer.

Comment: Btw: I have no refund to claim over Stephen Cleary's article https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html

Comment: Then you misunderstood the article. I was referring to the idea that you need yet another Task though, not whether you can start a task on top of another. No matter what `DoSomething()` does, you don't need anything more than `await` to work with it. The problem is caused by calling `Wait()` and `GetResult()` in the first place

Answer (score 2):

`Get()` isn't an overload, it's just a method that is called in response to a `GET` request because of Web API's conventions and routing configuration. If you want it to use `await`, just change its signature:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        await DoSomething();
        return ControllerContext?.ToString();  
    }

    Task DoSomething()=> Task.Delay(new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100));

}
```

That's all it takes to make it asynchronous.

Your code dealocks because you *freeze* the original thread/synchronization context  with `.GetResult()` before `await Task.Delay(new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100));` had a chance to return. With the original sync context frozen, `await` can't return.

The call to `task.ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't do anything, because you aren't awaiting that task anywhere. You are immediatelly blocking on it. You could avoid the deadlock if you used in with `await Task.Delay()`, ie `await Task.Delay().ConfigureAwait(false);` but that just covers up the problem of blocking in the first place

Comment: await Task.Delay().ConfigureAwait(false); would fix the issue.

Comment: What if DoSomething was a third party method I couldn't modify. Do you know how I could make the call in Get withouth making it async (which is part of this excercice's requirement)?

Comment: You mean like HttpClient? `async Task<string> Get(){ var client=new HttpClient()...); var result=await client.GetStringAsync(...); ...; return finalResult;}` You don't have to change *anything* in any third party method that already returns a task

Answer (score 0):

> How can this be solved, knowing the methods signature must not change* (for this exercice to bear any meaning to me)?
>
> Sometimes in life you don't have full control over the whole codebase and there are signatures you have to accept and deal with.

What you're asking for is how to consume asynchronous code in synchronous code. The example code is a poor choice for this question, because in the example ASP.NET controller code you *do* have control over your method signature.

In short, consuming asynchronous code in synchronous code is a bad idea. As you explore this out, you'll find that there are a variety of hacks, but **none** of them work correctly in every scenario. E.g., [the "blocking hack" can easily cause deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) when there is a `SynchronizationContext`, as you discovered.

You should always strive to use [`async` all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Seriously, the best answer to "how do I do this" is *"you don't!"* If you think about it for a bit, this makes sense; synchronous code (by definition) blocks a thread, and asynchronous code (by definition) does not. So, your asynchronous code is going through all the trouble to be asynchronous, only to be called by blocking code, which completely removes all the benefits of asynchronous code in the first place! It's better to go fully-async (or fully-sync). This is why [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43655219/263693) is good; it's the best answer *for your example code*.

However, there are a handful of rare scenarios where sync-over-async can't be avoided. In those situations, you need to adopt one of the hacks detailed in my article on [brownfield `async`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Comment: I understand the motive to put async on the Get method, as I said, it's an exercise.  I didn't think specifying the limitations verbally instead of specifying them in the code would cause so much debate. I will put it in a new way since code seems to override question.